# Split Page if specific code path includes more lines

Tags: html, split, web-scraping

I have used the split page method to extract certain parts of the website. Now I want to extract the 5,217 from the second code. I have been using the first method to extract code from the website:

> def idNotation(x):
>       request = urllib2.Request("WEBSITE URL")
>       handle = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>       content = handle.read()
>       splitted_page = content.split("part before the split")
>       splitted_page = splitted_page[1].split("part after the split")
>
> ```
> value =  splitted_page[0].replace(",",".")
> value = value.replace(",",".")
> return value
> ```

For the following code this method does not work:

```
    <tr>
                <td class="bold">
                    Hebel                        <a class="popup icon info right" href="/de/boersenportal/tools-und-services/glossar/glossar/?glossar_word=hebel"></a>
                </td>
                <td class="nowrap last">5,217</td>
            </tr>
```

Because the:

> td class="nowrap last"

occurs many times in the source code. I have to include the code below in the first part of the split page to receive the desired part. The problem is the blank spaces and because the split page method I have been using does not work if you include so many different lines of code.

I am looking for a method to extract only 5,217

> ```
>     Hebel                        <a class="popup icon info right" href="/de/boersenportal/tools-und-services/glossar/glossar/?glossar_word=hebel"></a>
>                 </td>
>                 <td class="nowrap last">
> ```

Comment: This is very much a hard way to extract information from a web page. I can tell you at least one better way. It would help if you could give us the url of the page you are scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are parsing a page similar to https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/de/boersenportal/wertpapiere-und-maerkte/anlageprodukte/factsheet/?ID_NOTATION=154844044, that you want information from the part of the page labelled 'Kennzahlen' and that you are specifically interested in the number to the right of the word 'Hebel' in such a page.

This code will get that for you. Of course it's hideous until you get used to it.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/de/boersenportal/wertpapiere-und-maerkte/anlageprodukte/factsheet/?ID_NOTATION=154844044').content
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> scrapings = Selector(text=page)
>>> scrapings.xpath('.//td[contains(text(),"Hebel")]/following-sibling::td[@class="nowrap last"]/text()').extract()
['5,084']
```

`Selector` processes `page` so that elements of the page can be identified using any of hundreds of *xpath* expressions. In this case, roughly speaking:

- `.//`: Look everywhere in the page.
- `td[contains(text(),"Hebel")]`: Find a `td` element whose text contains 'Hebel'. I didn't say 'equals' because the desired string is surrounded by blanks.
- `following-sibling`: Consider the sibling of that `td` that follow it.
- `::td[@class="nowrap last"]`: Limit consideration of these siblings to the one that is a `td` whose `class` is like this.
- `text()`: Get the `td` element's text.
- `.extract()`: Make whatever was found by the xpath available to Python. In this case it's a list. Usually this is the case.

http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/xpath.html is really handy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am glad that you understood my issue, because I am no native English speaker and because it was difficult to explain. I will try your solution!

Comment: this is the Url of the original page: https://www.boerse-stuttgart.de/de/boersenportal/wertpapiere-und-maerkte/hebelprodukte/knock-out-produkte/factsheet/?ID_NOTATION=193871326

Comment: Works the same way! If this answer works for you please mark it 'accepted'. Until you are confident in using this approach you can just post more questions. I see most of the questions.

Comment: Thanks, I have 'accepted' your solution and it was exactly what I've been looking for! The only thing I am getting confused with is that the output is in my case [u'5,084']. How can I remove the "u" to only get the float 5,084 ? It's probably a stupid question, but I started programming just a month ago.

Comment: The 'u' just means that it's a unicode string. You don't remove that. To make it into a float, assuming it's in `result`, use the following expression `float(result[0].replace(',', ''))`. (Get the first element of `result`, replace the commas with empty strings, calculate the floating point value of the string.)

Comment: Forgot: thanks for accepting, glad it worked for you.

Comment: Again, thank you very much, replacing the u worked fine as well and now the program functions perfectly